# Windows 8 software keyboard options

Tags: windows-8, tablet

On a Windows 8 tablet such as Surface, is it possible to replace the built-in software keyboard with a different one, such as SlideIt?

Answer (score 0):

Since third party Desktop apps are not allowed on Windows RT, the only way possible would be if a Store app were available that could do this.